# Basic libGDX project runs on 47-48 fps

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I created empty(only with badlogic texture) libGDX project and tested it on my android device *"Jiayu G2S"*. And it was running on 47-48 fps instead of 60. I thought my device is not fast enough for testing, but now i have half-finished game with a lot of drawings and calculations, but fps is still 47-48. What can be a problem? How can i increase it to 60?

LibGDX's version is 1.6.4

Testing on API16(Android 4.1.2)

Comment: its a very tough question because i cant say anything without seeing your code. I have once summarized few key things for optimization. have a worth looking.Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347883/why-game-is-running-slow-in-libgdx/17360381#17360381

Comment: The game works with same fps when i have standart libGDX project with only one texture drawing and when i have many textures, sounds and calculations. It is not about optimization, because empty project and half-finished project runs on the same fps. That's the problem...

Comment: is this happening to other devices also?

Comment: I am sure on Desktop this will work on 60 fps, because i saw some question about low fps with empty canvas on android. However, this guy only created libGDX project, so this could be device with low-performance. I have situation when it works on the same fps when i have a lot of methods called and when i have empty black canvas doing nothing. Could it be because of sending debug information to computer? I just have no idea and i don't know what to do.

Comment: Is it a problem your game runs at 47-48 FPS? I would not worry about the fps unless it is fluctuating noticeably or dropping too low.

Comment: My game is binded to fps. Every 1/60 seconds it does some calculations and draws the objects. Also, i have sound what longs 5 seconds and while it goes, music pauses and when 300 frames went it plays again. There's really noticeable delay between stopping 5 seconds sound and playing the music. I am sure, dividing actions and drawing on Threads won't do anything useful.

Comment: Don't bind your physics / logic to fps. This is a great read on why not, and how to fix it: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: Next time i won't bind it to fps, but now i really need to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my device's maximum display refresh rate is 47.49, it can't go higher.

The smartest solution of this problem would be creating a seperate thread for game's logic and calculate how many times it should be executed before calling render() method. It will fix this problem for all display refresh rates.