# libGDX: FPS on Android device is low

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my game I have created many loops and methods inside `render`. The FPS range in my laptop ranges from `56` to `60`, which is ok. However, when I run it in the Android OS on a Galaxy Note 4, the range of FPS ranges from `24` to `45`, which is not ok.

Now I need a new render thread, to render synchronously with:

```
Gdx.app.getApplicationListener().render();
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Since you have not given it is very hard to judge what causes your FPS to slow down, However you can read this Question maybe u get a clue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347883/why-game-is-running-slow-in-libgdx/17360381#17360381

Comment: Wow, its even possible to have 2 render threads in libgdx? and why whould you need that?

Comment: Thanx a lot @KumarSaurabh , I created objects already in render, So I used `pool<Object>` and FPS is Ok. Ya that's it. thx again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even a low end laptop usually has much more processing power than a high end smartphone, thus what performs smoothly on your laptop can lag behind terribly on your Galaxy Note.

You've provided almost no information in the question, so the things I can suggest are general approaches;

- **Profile** the game on your phone, and find possible bottlenecks, so you
  can deal with them.
  http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html
- **OpenGL profiling** will also be very helpful, you can monitor context
  switches and more with it.
  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Profiling
- Also as a general rule of thumb, do not create new objects in the
  render loop, or do it as little as possible if absolutely necessary.
  Initializing a **pool of reusable objects** at start will help you a lot.
  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management

Comment: I got it. @Davlumbaz I already created objects in render :(. So, I used pool for actors. My problem solved and FPS will be ok :) . thanks again.