# Create monster and set position of tiledMap #java #libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I've a problem with setting my monster on the map. Firstly I create a Knight with camera coordinates. Now I want to set a monster on the map independent of the camera coordinates, so that when I am moving the player using keys the monster stays at the one position. I tried to implemets this and all I got was that the monster stayed at the bottom left corner of the screen all the time. Here is my Person class

```
public abstract class Person implements Stats {

public Person(String pathToFile,Vector2 position) {
    ...
}

public void update(float delta) {
    spriteBatch.begin();
    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

And my bot class

```
public class Bot extends Person {

public Bot() {
    super(toFilePath,new Vector2(500,550));
    super.position.set(500,550);
}

@Override
public void update(float delta) {
    super.update(delta);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}
```

}

The Knight class

```
 public class Knight extends Person {

public Knight(OrthographicCamera camera) {

    super(toFilePath, new Vector2(MapScreen.startPositionX, MapScreen.startPositionY));
    super.sprite.setCenter(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2);
    this.camera = camera;
    // animation
    ...
}

public void update(float delta, MapScreen mapScreen) {
    camera.update();
    walkBatch.begin();
    // input handling
    walkBatch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    ...
}
```

And the class where I set up all classes

```
public class MapScreen implements Screen {

...

@Override
public void show() {
    init(startPositionX, startPositionY);
}

// initialize variable
private void init(float posX, float posY) {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader(new ExternalFileHandleResolver()).load(mapName);
    setTiledMapRenderer(new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap));
    knight = new Knight(camera);
    camera.zoom = ZOOM;
    camera.position.set(posX, posY, 0);
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camera.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    getTiledMapRenderer().setView(camera);
    getTiledMapRenderer().render(layerBottom);
    knight.update(delta, this);

    getTiledMapRenderer().render(layerTop);
}
```

Comment: You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. I created a object layer in Tiled and there I set my monsters. Then in MapScreen I render it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When using a [SpriteBatch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) (which you probably don't use at all, when looking at your code), then you can use your camera's matrix to calculate the offsets correctly.

use it like:

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
spriteBatch.begin();
// draw your sprites here
spriteBatch.end();
```

You should then also consider improve performances by not rendering sprites off the screen:

[Consider implementing some of the tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21759934/1019562)