# Infinite Runner Lags after a while

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I am creating a simple infinite runner game for the android os using the libgdx framework, I have everything working fairly well but then I noticed that after a while mayne 2 or 3 minutes in the fps drops steadily until it goes all the way to 0... I am creating the game assets every 10 or so seconds and then setting their bodies active to false when they are out of screen, it was my understanding that it would not calculate for them after this but it slows down when I run the assets and it doesn't slow down when I don't run the assets...my question is is this normal and should I dispose of these assets a different way? how do other infinite runner games deal with this lag issue, also I am loading the texture from my asset manager so I believe it is only using the one texture instead of creating many....

Comment: Profile your code.  That will give you some clues about what is happening.

Comment: I mean im asking a very specific question here, 

I am moving assets across the screen and when it ends up on the left side I set their bodies (from box2d) to inactive, is this wrong ? after a few loops of these assets being walked across screen and turned off the game drops fps, is this so random that no one has experienced something similar?

Comment: If you are talking about something specific, create an MCVE so that people can understand what you are actually doing.  (The chances are that you are doing something wrong, but people need to see your code to make that call.)

Comment: okay so you are saying you've never heard of fps dropping overtime in an endless runner game?

Comment: Not for reasons that can't be attributed to bugs or implementation mistakes in the game!  But if you are just looking for some general advice, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347883/why-game-is-running-slow-in-libgdx

Comment: "Not for reasons that can't be attributed to bugs or implementation mistakes" this was kinda the answer I was looking for, I appreciate your time, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

okay so after testing all day I see that the game slows down after a while because its still rendering the images even after they leave the screen, I implemented a method to stop rendering them after a certain point and start rendering a new series of backgrounds, its a work around to be sure but im one step closer to my goal so ill take it as a win.